# Laravel project on ubuntu server :HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-5

My laravel project works fine in development machine, but when i uploaded to ubuntu server i will get  `HTTP ERROR 500`.

Here is things i've done.

1.Uploaded the entire contents of `<laravel_project>` folder into the `var\www\html folder`.

when i try to access `domain.com` i will get the list of directories instead of home page,when entering on `public` folder i will get `HTTP ERROR 500` error.

Also how can get the index page without accessing the public folder (ie i need to enter to my site while entering  `domain.com` ) .

Comment: We don't know which http server software you use (`nginx`, `Apache`, something else). We don't know how PHP is configured. We don't know your http server configuration. You didn't inspect http server error logs. Basically, you didn't do anything or provide anything we can use to help you. Please, do basic error analysis before asking for help. Find out which http server software you use, find out where it keeps its logs, read the logs, try to determine from them what went wrong and if you still fail - come back with more information.

Comment: Apache is my server software give me sometime to update with the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple cases

1. Please check you can storage write permission to storage folder
2. You need to define path to public in your apache configuration to be able to open without public
3. Server does not meet the minimum requirements of Laravel

Please try above and let me know

Comment: Storage permission is enabled so how to define path to public in apache configuration?

Comment: Can you provide me the Url

Comment: You can contact me directly to ajay@froiden.com

Comment: I will  contact you

Comment: you can change the document root  folder on the apache configuration. go to the configuration file (usually called `000-default.conf`) which located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and edit the line that says : `DocumentRoot`  to whatever you need (in your case `/var/www/html/public`).

Comment: @AfikDeri its worked how can i see the http error logs?

Comment: @shammon You can look at your php.ini file to find the exact location but by default it's in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change Document root directory in apache configure file.
File Location in Ubuntu Server is : 
1) `$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-available` 2) `$ gedit 000-default.conf`

Find the default Directory Root and modify it with your project_directory / public_directory.

i.e. `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_dir/public/`

See this code for referance :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_dir/public_dir

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

After edit this file. Reload apache server once.

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```